# Arm Assembly - Getting wrong output

Tags: assembly, arm

My goal is to take the numbers in the ary label and categorize them into their appropriate generation. The current problem i am having is that the output i am getting is completely off. Would it be that my loop is incorrent?

The output i am expecting is

```
Greatest Generation: 1
Generation X: 1
Not Applicable: 1
```

What I am currently getting is

```
Lost Generation: 66328
Generation Y: 1995673600
```

Below is what I have

```
            .data
    str1:   .asciz  "Lost Generation: %d\n"
    str2:   .asciz  "Greatest Generation: %d\n"
    str3:   .asciz  "Baby Boomer Generation: %d\n"
    str4:   .asciz  "Generation X: %d\n"
    str5:   .asciz  "Generation Y: %d\n"
    str6:   .asciz  "Generation Z: %d\n"
    str7:   .asciz  "Not Applicable: %d\n"
    ary:    .word   100,40,5
            .equ    arysize,(. - ary)/4

            .text
            .global main

    main:   stmfd   sp!,{lr}
            ldr     r1,=ary
            ldr     r2,=arysize
            mov     r0,#0

    read:   cmp     r0,r2
            beq     prtlg
            ldr     r1,[r3]
            add     r1,#4
            add     r0,r0,#1
            b       lg

    lg:     cmp     r1,#127
            ble     lg2
            add     r12,r12,#1
            b       read

    lg2:    cmp r1,#102
        blt gg
        add r6,r6,#1
        b   read

    gg: cmp r1,#101
        ble gg2     

    gg2:    cmp r1,#93
        blt bb
        add r7,r7,#1
        b   read

    bb: cmp r1,#71
        ble bb2

    bb2:    cmp r1,#53
        blt gx
        add r8,r8,#1
        b   read

    gx: cmp r1,#52
        ble gx2

    gx2:    cmp r1,#38
        blt gy
        add r9,r9,#1
        b   read

    gy: cmp r1,#36
        ble gy2

    gy2:    cmp r1,#22
        blt gz
        add r10,r10,#1
        b   read

    gz: cmp r1,#21
        ble gz2

    gz2:    cmp r1,#7
        blt na
        add r11,r11,#1
        b   read

    na: add r12,r12,#1
        b   read

    prtlg:  cmp r6,#0
        beq prtgg
        ldr r0,=str1
        mov r1,r6
        bl  printf
        b   prtgg

    prtgg:  cmp r7,#0
        beq prtbb
        ldr r0,=str2
        mov r1,r7
        bl  printf
        b   prtbb

    prtbb:  cmp r8,#0
        beq prtgx
        ldr r0,=str3
        mov r1,r8
        bl  printf
        b   prtgx

    prtgx:  cmp r9,#0
        beq prtgy
        ldr r0,=str4
        mov r1,r9
        bl  printf
        b   prtgy

    prtgy:  cmp r10,#0
        beq prtgz
        ldr r0,=str5
        mov r1,r10
        bl  printf
        b   prtgz

    prtgz:  cmp r11,#0
        beq prtna
        ldr r0,=str6
        mov r1,r11
        bl  printf
        b   prtna

    prtna:  cmp r12,#0
        beq end
        ldr r0,=str7
        mov r1,r12
        bl  printf
        b   end

    end:    ldmfd   sp!,{lr}
            mov     pc,lr
            .end
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your program? To step through the code statement by statement (while monitoring registers and their values) to make sure it does what you want?

Comment: I have not but can you point me in the direction as to where to get started on that please? Thank you @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Use a debugger, like GDB.  A debugger is an essential tool for programming, especially in asm where it's hard to use debug-prints.

Comment: You might also want to provide some more details about just what _"categorize them into their appropriate generation"_ means. It's not clear why your expected output is what you say it is.